# Cabal: executable data-files

Tags: haskell, cabal

I want to include an executable file in the cabal `data-files` section to execute it as a subprocess in my Haskell program.

The file's there, `getDataFileName` works for it, but it lacks the executable bit and so trying to run it with `System.Process.createProcess` fails with `permission denied`.

Is there a way for cabal to preserve the execution permission of the file? Is there another clean way to solve this?

Comment: You may need to solve it with a custom `Setup.hs` file and a post-install hook. Though in that case, I'd probably just modify your code to set the executable bit before calling `createProcess`, since custom `Setup.hs` files can be a PITA

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman: But I think that my code wouldn't necessarily have the permissions to set the executable bit, if it is installed in system dirs and executed by a user

Comment: You're correct. In that case, you may need to use the Setup.hs option, or resort to ugly tricks like copying the file to a temporary location and then setting the executable bit.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman: I now tried using the custom `Setup.hs` option, but it seems like it can't be done currently due to Cabal not calling the hooks - https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1805

Comment: How about using the `copy` hook instead of an `install` hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As summarized in some [discussion](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/commit/dda6ffed28f10f521f9c0d3cb0773a46ae3940f1) on cabal patches, the current (underdocumented) state of play is that one should use both a copy *and* an install hook, since one or the other will get executed.

Edit: After some digging, there's an [old ticket on libexec support](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/708) in cabal, which would be a very nice solution if it were implemented.

Comment: Regarding the second solution - @MichaelSnoyman also suggested that above but we concluded that it won't necessarily work since the app may be ran by a user without permissions to change the globally installed data files.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the problematic second solution, to accept the first one as the answer.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. I was googling for a working example but no luck. Has this changed in the meantime? Thanks!